# Ajax actionLink posting to new page instead of updating page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update page with server time using ajax.actionlink; i was able to do this in regular js. Now ajax takes me to new page and its url is home/serverTime  ;serverTime is my homecontroller action. Surprisingly the code works even without referencing MicrosoftAjax/ MicrosoftMvcAjax. I am using VS 2013 mvc 4.5

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>Ajax</h2>
<div class="jumbotron" id="display">

    
    @Ajax.ActionLink("click here get time", "ServerTime",
    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "display"
})
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the needed js files (to make it ajaxified) included in the page. (`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`)

Comment: You need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` (without it, `@Ajax.ActionLink()` falls back to making a normal redirect)

Comment: I did this in _Layout  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>


</head>

Comment: Delete `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` - they are not required (and are obsolete). But you do need `jquery-{version}.js` before `/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`

Comment: thanks it is working! so why delete ms ajax?

Comment: All Microsoft* helpers are obsolete in ASP.NET MVC 3.